# How to do a mathematical sum in R?

Tags: r, math

I have the following mathematical formula that I want to program as efficiently as possible in R.

$\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)$

Let's say we have the following example data:

```
x = c(1,5,7,10,11)
y = c(2,4,8,9,12)
```

How can I easily get this sum with this data without making a separate function?
Isn't there a package or a function that can compute these mathematical sums?

Comment: Yeah I know about this lm() function. I use that function a lot. But I was just wondering if there are easy fixes for mathematical functions like these. You'd think there'd something out there that can fix something this easy.

Comment: Well, your question asks if there is such a function to compute these quantities, and I point out that it exists in base R, and you agree.... So I think I've provided a full and complete answer to the question.

Comment: Ok, then I've not formulated it well. I'm not interested in regression, but interested in solving such mathematical summations in gerenal. I've removed the regression part bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `sum` command and vectorized operations: `sum((x-mean(x))*(y-mean(y)))`

The key revelation here is that the sum function is just taking the sum over the argument (vector, matrix, whatever). In this case, it's sufficient to give it a vector, and in this case, the vector expression is a little more complicated than `sum(z)`, but notice that `(x-mean(x))*(y-mean(y))` evaluates to `z`, so the fact that the command is slightly ornate doesn't really change how the function works. This is true in many places, not just the `sum` command.

Comment: Wouldn't they be the coefficients going through zero?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: It seems as though he is defining the slope of the OLS regression line going through the origin.

Comment: In general the slope is $\hat \beta_1=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_iX_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^2}$

Comment: Nonono, I'm not interested in regression, I'm interested in functions that can calculate such kind of summations.

Comment: @AntoniParellada I disagree, and if he wants ROTE, then you can suppress the intercept, but the distinction appears to be irrelevant because OP has changed the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks I didn't know I could do that with the sum function. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Ansjovis86 No problem. The key revelation here is that the sum function is just taking the sum over the argument (vector, matrix, whatever). In this case, it's sufficient to give it a vector, and in this case, the vector expression is a little more complicated than `sum(z)`, but notice that `(x-mean(x))*(y-mean(y))` evaluates to `z`, so the fact that the command is slightly ornate doesn't really change how the function works. This is true in many places, not just the `sum` command.